# Problems with rewrite rule

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I realy cant to figure this out.

What i want to do, is this URI http://www.hotels-lithuania.net/index.php?page=76&type=hotels&id=1 transform to http://www.hotels-lithuania.net/item/hotels/1.
Actualy i have read tons of pages, what i come to is this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?',
        'index.php?page=76&type=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'type';
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

If I enter hotels-lithuania.net/item/hotels/1 to my browser it cuts to hotels-lithuania.net/item/ and ofc no items displayed.

Screen from rewrite analyzer plugin: i.stack.imgur.com/AgNoq.png

Sorry for bad hyperlinks, but i am new here and can't post ir proper

EDIT:
I dont know why, but i had guid in my db with value localhost/hotel/?**page_id=76** 
So my final rewrite_rule looks like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?',
        'index.php?page_id=76&itemType=$matches[1]&itemId=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'itemType';
    $query_vars[] = 'itemId';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

And using these variables with:

```
global $wp;
$type = $wp->query_vars['itemType'];
$id = $wp->query_vars['itemId'];
```

Comment: Screen from rewrite analyzer plugin: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AgNoq.png

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a conflict with your query vars. `id` is already a WordPress query var, and `type` is a reserved word. You should use vars that you know will be unique among core and any plugin you may use by prefixing everything, like `zilvinas_id` and `zilvinas_type`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tryed your sollution, but still no good. If i try http://www.hotels-lithuania.net/item/hotel/1 it cuts my variables.
http://i48.tinypic.com/2zoc1ad.png

Comment: Are you resaving your permalinks after you modify the rewrites function?